# Selenium Web-Driver Firefox Profile - Disable popup and alert windows

Tags: java, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a problem with certain websites that cause my browser to prompt an alert when I try to switch to a different URL, or even close the browser. Some examples:

- http://grooveshark.com/
- http://www.dollardays.com/

In order to workaround the alert with Selenium, I need to switch to that alert, and then sometimes accept it and sometimes reject it (depending on the contents of the alert).

I wish to avoid solving this problem that way because:

1. I need to guess whether I should accept the alert or reject the alert.
2. Switching to the alert sometimes throws an exception, **even though** the alert is present.

What preferences do I need to set in the Firefox-Profile, in order to prevent the browser from issuing such alerts (or any other alerts for that matter)?

Answers in Java or Python will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

To my knowledge you can only disable that behaviour globally.
There is a preference called **dom.disable_beforeunload**. You should change its value to true. With Selenium, you can create a new customized Firefox profile:

```
FirefoxProfile customProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
customProfile.setPreference("dom.disable_beforeunload", true);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(customProfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's not possible to disable native browser events like alerts, so you'll just have to handle them better.

1) You should be able to use `alert.getText()` to make an informed decision on whether to accept or dismiss an alert.

:

```
try { 
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2); 
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
     Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
     if ( alert.getText().contains("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")) {
         alert.accept();
     }
     else if ( alert.getText().contains("Some other text which means you need to dismiss")) {
         alert.dismiss();
     }
     else {
         //something else
     }
}
catch (Exception e) {

}
```

2) Use a WebDriverWait to avoid race conditions. See above

Comment: I am not interested in handling alerts, for the reasons explained above. To emphasize this, various alerts have various different texts, from which one cannot infer whether the alert should be accepted or rejected.

Comment: And there is no racing problem whatsoever. The alert appears as soon as you try to navigate away from the website (either to a different website, or when closing down the browser altogether).

Comment: 1) Maybe getType can be used to determine whether the alert can be accepted or rejected. 2) What exception is thrown in 2? If it's AlertNotPresent then you have a race condition, your code is executing before the browser has finished displaying the alert. This may not be visible to the naked eye, remember.

Comment: thanks. The 2nd issue is less critical as far as I'm concerned. My problem really is, getting those alerts to begin with. There is no such thing as 'getType' for an alert as far as I'm aware of. It simply contains two options, and I need to pick one of them. Perhaps the correct terminology is 'prompt-window' or 'confirm-window' rather than 'alert-window'.

Comment: Sorry, getType is a C# thing that doesn't do what I thought. See revised answer, is there some reason you cannot use getText like that?

Comment: Yes, in fact there is. The text you're suggesting for me to test is what they call in forensic science "circumstantial evidence". I have no guarantee what kind of text exists in each and every alert "out there", hence I have no full-proof method for asserting whether I need to accept a given alert or reject it. It is also mentioned within the question, as a matter of fact... Though, I appreciate the efforts, so thanks...

Comment: At some point you need to have an understanding of the possible outcomes of your actions. I figured that you were expecting to put some sort of logic into your tests when you said "depending on the contents of the alert". How many different alerts are you actually coming across that you cannot account for them in this way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Firefox profile would feature disabling such specific elements, but you can hard-code some lines of static logic that would remain consistent across the test case/project.

Like **Click** on the main page automatically closes the pop-up frame/alert msg on grooveshark.com

```
    @Test
  public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/#!/genre/Rap/1748"); //complete URL becomes http://grooveshark.com/#!/genre/Rap/1748
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("more…")).click(); // clicks a hyper-link which opens up that frame/pop-up
    driver.findElement(By.id("lightbox-outer")).click(); // clicks outside the opened-up frame, or simply clicks on the main page in background
  }
```

**lightbox-outer** is the main page.

Comment: Can you please add a short description for each line?

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the popups (alert), just do alert.accept() means clicking the ok button of alert modal or alert.dismiss() means clicking the cancel or close button.

The worst in this case is that you need to wait a certain time if you are not very sure that alert is going to be present or not.

If the alert is present as a result of event sucess( just like clicing the button, webpage asks for your confirmation ) you dont need to do wait  `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());`
 you can save the time by going to next step which is switching the drver to alert. i.e

```
 Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
     if ( alert.getText().contains("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")) {
         alert.accept();
     }
     else if ( alert.getText().contains("Some other text which means you need to dismiss")) {
         alert.dismiss();
     }
     else {
         //something else
     }
}
```

just to be sure you can use a small waiting time, but yes it depends uponthe network speed to load the web page for the case that alert is present when webpage is loaded.

Comment: and if you disable teh behaviour globally, by configuring your profile no any alert will appear for that profile. You need to know how convenient is this for our application.