# Python and Selenium - Disable all alerts

Tags: python, selenium

Using **Python 3** and *Selenium* > **Chromedriver**.

I am running a python script to scrape stuff from different web sites.

I need to open and close a lot of different sites.

**Problem**:

My program crashes when an alert is fired.

> selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
>   Message: unexpected alert open

What am I **trying** to fix the situation?

When I do **driver.get()**, i immediately run:

```
driver.execute_script("window.alert = null;")
driver.execute_script("Window.prototype.alert = null;")
```

Right before doing **driver.close()**, I run:

```
driver.execute_script("window.onbeforeunload = null;")
```

Right after doing **driver.close()**, I do:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

...

driver.close()
# any alert asking me if I really want to close?
try:
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
except NoAlertPresentException:
    pass
```

**What am I achieving?**

Nothing, the program keeps crashing:

[image]

**Question**:

How may I set up the whole thing, to disable every alert.

If not possible, how may I accept them all or at least do so that the program keeps flowing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Web-Driver Firefox Profile - Disable popup and alert windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974729/selenium-web-driver-firefox-profile-disable-popup-and-alert-windows)

Comment: I don't see a popup there when I access the site. Can you please translate whats the popup all about? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB It is the typical "Are you sure you want to leave this page?" popup. And it happens to appear only sometimes.

Comment: Are you using the same driver instance to browse to another url? I can see you using `driver.close()` why not `driver.quit()`? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB I use driver close insetad of quit so that I can keep using the same driver ;)

Comment: @ÁlvaroN.Franz I think I have an answer to your question but I need to ensure a fact that normally "Are you sure" popup is observed when we try to browse backwards or refresh a page when the page loading is underway. But that doesn't seems to be your case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job, include this after the alert

```
try:
    alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
except:
    print("No Alert")
```

I'm still trying to figure out a way in which whenever this alert window appears this code will run.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to modify the `window` object by setting `windows.alert = null`.
and just call `driver.execute_script(...)`
However, if alert pops at page loading then this wont work. also won't work for `async execution`

Best way to handle this issue is to create a google extension and make sure to enable `web_accessible_resources` within the `manifest.json` file, which is a way to to authorize extensions to modify the window object.

Answer (score -12):

This has been asked a lot of times, have you done any research prior to asking the question?

This should help you along, it's taken from the website mentioned below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/handling-alerts-using-selenium-webdriver/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    // This step will result in an alert on screen
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/p[4]/button")).click();

    Alert simpleAlert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    String alertText = simpleAlert.getText();
    System.out.println("Alert text is " + alertText);
    simpleAlert.accept();
}
```

[Source](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/handling-of-alerts-javascript-alerts-and-popup-boxes/)

Comment: Would you care to 'translate' it to python?

Comment: Yes, I did my research. You did not provide anything I didn't already try, as you can read in my question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroN.Franz I disagree, you havn't tried setting any ChromeOptions. Keep downvoting.

Comment: I did not downvote you. You took the time to help ;)