# How to close download popup in Chrome using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When you download a file in Chrome, you are displayed with a pop-up on the bottom of the screen with the name of the downloaded file. How can I close it using Selenium Webdriver with Python after the file is downloaded?

Comment: [Try this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319743/python-and-selenium-disable-all-alerts?rq=1) This deals with disabling alerts in selenium.

Comment: @HusseinEsmail When I do `browser.execute_script("windows.alert = null")`, I get `Message: unknown error: windows is not defined`. What is the proper way to disable alerts?

Comment: I don’t think this is how you’re supposed to do it. ‘window.alert = null’ is it’s own line, window being whatever you named your window variable.

Comment: @sprogissd what are you trying to do? That you want to close it, what's the usecase?

Comment: There is child window also appearing so you need to handle windows selenium and you can close it.

Comment: @NorayrSargsyan Here is the usecase. I click on a link do download a file, the gets downloaded, and a pop-up window with the file name appears on the bottom of Chrome. If I keep browsing, that pop-up window stays. How do I close it?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # or Chrome/Opera/Safari/Edge
# after
# your
# code
# to
# download
# file


### if the pop-up is a new window ###
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.close() # closes currently active window
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) # switch back to main window

### if the pop-up is more like a text box overlaid on top of the page ###
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Note that if run `driver.close()` and you only have one window or tab open with Selenium, your Selenium session is discarded and if you try to run `driver.close()` again you will get an error like the following:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
```

To avoid this issue, you can use `driver.quit()`, which doesn't throw an exception even when you already closed your Selenium session. An even better way would be to use a context manager using the `with` keyword, so even when you hit some error while using Selenium, you won't need to manually close it yourself.

Hope this helped!

Comment: When I try your approach, I get this: `unknown error: windows is not defined`

Comment: Where did you enter `windows`? None of the commands I mentioned use `windows`. You tried `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1]) `?

Comment: Sorry, I provided a wrong error. The error that I get is `list index out of range` when `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])` is executed.

Comment: try this then: `driver.switch_to.alert.accept()` Also edited main post to include both cases :)

Comment: When I do `driver.switch_to.alert.accept()`, I get this error: `no such alert`.